# Django-postgres-extesion ArrayRemove

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hey I'm trying to add network monitoring parameter values `int` into a Django models `ArrayField` every minute for further processing.

Django-postgres-extension sounded promising for my purposes, but now I'm struggling with couple of issues.
Im adding values `int` to my array using:

```py
MyMeasData.objects.filter(ipAddress=ipa).update(paramOne = ArrayPrepend(param1, 'ParamOne'))
```

but I need to keep my array length under n samples by removing last value of the array.

- Q1: what is the correct syntax to remove last value of the `Array`? All my attempts have failed,

```
MyMeasData.objects.filter(ipAddress=ipa).update(paramOne = ArrayRemove('paramOne', [-1]))
```

- Q2: How do I get the size of queryset `paramOne`, so I know when to start `ArrayRemove` in `Q1`?

```
MyMeasData.objects.filter(ipAddress = ipa).values_list('paramOne', flat = True)
```

gives a `queryset`:

```
<QuerySet [[903, 903, 901, 903, 901, 901, 901, 899]]>
```

I have looked into the `django-postgres-extension` documentation, but wasn't able figure out the correct syntax.

I'm using:

- python 3.8.8
- django 3.2.7